# Changing colour of text in function php file

Tags: wordpress

Hey I have an additional information tab on my wordpress site.

i already added a function to change what the text says see below:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Click Here for Dimensions' );   
// Rename the additional information tab


    return $tabs;

}
```

---

but I want to be able to make this text appear in red. any ideas?
link tosite - https://linenandleather.co.uk/product/round-wooden-board-black/

I have not tried anyhting yet, dont dare

Comment: That title probably gets output as plain text, so even if you hacked some additional HTML into there, it likely won't work. You should handle this via your stylesheet - the `li` element this particular tab title is in, has the class `additional_information_tab`and the ID `tab-title-additional_information`, so that should be more than enough already to properly target it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, any idea how i do this?? I am not well versed in code

Comment: Basically, `#tab-title-additional_information a { color: red; }` should do. (Using the ID instead of the class makes more sense here, because the selector that applies the current color is a bit more complex, and the ID gives this one higher specificity.) Now whether you have a separate child theme were you can modify the style sheet directly, I don't know; if not, you can probably also hack it into one of the "custom CSS" plugins that are out there.

Comment: my style sheet is just one massive block of text, do i just put it on the end?

Comment: IT WORKED THANKS

Comment: I just had to do custom CCS on the customize it was actually simple

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve this:

```
 add_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_for_tab_color');
function custom_css_for_tab_color() {
    echo '<style>
        .woocommerce-product-data ul.tabs li.additional_information_tab a {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

You can place this code in your theme's functions.php file. It will add custom CSS to your page's header, changing the color of the additional information tab text to red. Adjust the color property value to change it to the desired color. Make sure to clear any caching on your site after making this change to see the effects.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, but it didnt work :(((( i dont know what im doing wrong...

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

 $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Click Here for Dimensions' ); 
// Rename the additional information tab


 return $tabs;

}

 add_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_for_tab_color');
function custom_css_for_tab_color() {
    echo '<style>
        .woocommerce-product-data ul.tabs li.additional_information_tab a {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>';
}